# What WiFi authentication protocols does OS X support?

Tags: macos, wifi

I'm trying to find out how many types of WiFi authentications does OS X support. I know it's supports the basic WEP/WPA and even EAP-PEAP. Does anybody have the full list of supported WiFi authentication protocols?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From the Support article [Accessing 802.1X networks in OS X Lion](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4772):

> This process can be used to join networks with the following EAPOL
>   authentication types:
>
> - PEAP
> - TTLS (see note 1)
> - LEAP
> - EAP-FAST (see note 2)
> - TLS